# Export color corrected rasters from a catalog in arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, export, color, raster-catalog

I have several raster in a raster catalog for which I(ve used color correction. I'de like to export each raster as a geotiff with exactly the same resolution and world file than the original geotiff rasters. By exporting the selected rasters from the raster catalog with colors corrected, in a blank raster catalog (MANAGED), the image file is not created. 
Can you explain how to export color corrected rasters to georeferenced image files with teh same properties than the input rasters ?